# Adding class on hover event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a `submit` button. and a `textbox`. I would like to hover on `button` with `classname: search` ,then toggle class to my `textbox`.
the problem is it is not work when I want to type in my textbox. How can I fix this?
Here is my codes:

```js
$(".search").hover(function () {
    $(".searchinput").toggleClass("searchinput2");
 });
```

```css
.searchinput{width:2%; height:30px; background:yellow; font-size:1.5em;}
.searchinput2{width:50% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="searchinput"/>
        <button type="submit" class="search">search</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` events.

```js
$(".search").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#searchinput").addClass('searchinput2');
 });
$(".searchinput").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#searchinput").removeClass('searchinput2');
 });
```

```css
.searchinput{width:2%; height:30px; background:yellow; font-size:1.5em;}
.searchinput2{width:50% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="searchinput" id="searchinput"/>
        <button type="submit" class="search">search</button>
```

You can bind `.hover()` event handler for `input` element.

```js
$(".searchinput").hover(function () {
    $(".searchinput").toggleClass('searchinput2');
});
```

```css
.searchinput{width:2%; height:30px; background:yellow; font-size:1.5em;}
.searchinput2{width:50% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="searchinput"/>
        <button type="submit" class="search">search</button>
```

Comment: i would like to use this code with hover not click event

Comment: Although this solution works. But, I don't understand why it didn't with `hover`. As the doc says: **The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.**

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Thank you so much.

Comment: @Abhi, because `hover` is applied for `button` element and that's the reson for appearing this behavior. View updated answer.